# Pointer to pointer assignment and dereference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

Let's say I have a linked list node like the following:

```cpp
struct ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode *next;
  ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

The goal is to write a function to delete a node in a singly-linked list. One efficient way to do it in constant time is something like this:

```cpp
void deleteNode(ListNode* node) {
    auto *tmp = node->next;
    *node = *tmp;
    delete tmp;
}
```

This works, but why do we need to dereference the pointers?

If `node` is a pointer and `tmp` is a pointer, why does it need to dereferenced? Why can't I do `node = tmp`?

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) parameter has no effect outside the function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: If I understand it right, then you are actually copying the tmp_node to the current node, before you delete tmp.

Comment: If `*node = *tmp` does a copy of values, how I can just move `node`'s address (without any copy)?

Comment: "One efficient way to do it" I doubt it. Copying pointed-to objects instead of manipulating pointers is only efficient in cases of very small objects with non-complex assignment operators... With a pointer to the node **preceeding** the to be deleted one, things would be much more efficient. Please explain why that is not an option.

Comment: @Adrian It is an immutable absolute rule in C++ that under no circumstance can the address of an object change.

Answer (score 1):

When performing `*node=*tmp` you copy all the bytes of `*tmp` into `*node` thus
`node->val` now holds `tmp->val` and `node->next` now holds `tmp->next`.

The old content of `node` has been forgotten (it's normal since you want to get rid of this node) but you *saved* the content of the next node at this same place.
Then if you delete the next node (known through `tmp`) you don't lose its content (it has been saved in the previous node).

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the three lines of your `deleteNode` function:

```cpp
    auto *tmp = node->next;
```

This creates a local variable, `tmp` which will be a copy of the `next` field of the passed `node` parameter. This is a pointer to the next structure in the list and, once we've made a copy of it, we can erase or overwrite that member.

```cpp
    *node = *tmp;
```

This copies the *actual data* of the structure pointed to by `tmp` (that is, the *next* node in the list) to the *current* node, overwriting the `next` field as it does so. We need to dereference *both* pointers in order to copy the values of the structures pointed to.

```cpp
    delete tmp;
```

This deletes the 'next' node in the given list. However, we have already copied **all** its data (including its `next` member) into our current node, so our modified list now starts with (effectively) the second one in the original list (the passed parameter); notably, the `next` field of `*node` will now be the address originally stored in `node->next->next` – thus, we have 'skipped' an entry (the second) in the list and deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't just write `node = tmp` is because that wouldn't change anything outside of your function.

Given this linked list

```
node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3
```

If you want to delete node1, the desired outcome would be

```
node0 -> node2 -> node3
```

If you don't want to actively modify the pointer value (that is, the address `next`) in `node0`, you have to move the value inside `node2` to where `node1` was.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I do `node = tmp` ?

You can do that, but it won't do anything useful. `node` is a local variable in `deleteNode`. As it is a pointer you can use that local pointer to modify what it points to, but modfying the pointer itself has no effect outside of the function.

Actually pointers are not different with respect to that. You also cannot observe any effect from outside when you have

```
void foo(int x) {
    x = 42;
}
```

Passing a reference is different:

```
void bar(int& x) {
    x = 42;
}
int a = 0;
bar(a);    // now a == 42
```

Same with pointers:

```
void bar_ptr(int*& x) {
      x = nullptr;
}
int* b = &a;
bar_ptr(b);   // now b == nullptr
```

Answer (score 0):

What your function really does, is that it doesn't delete the node from the parameter, but the next node, overwriting the current node with the follower.

The dereferencing of the pointer acts like a `memcpy()` and moves the data from the next node to the current. You are not copying the pointers but the data it points to.

This way you can repeatedly call the function with the same node pointer, and it will move down the chain.
However, since you are not checking the pointer, the last node probably has a NULL pointer and will crash on derefencing.

So you need to do

```
 if (tmp)
     *node = *tmp;
```

Example:

```
typedef struct list
{
    struct list *next;
    int value;
} List;

void deleteNext(List* node)
{
    auto *tmp = node->next;

    if(tmp)
        *node = *tmp;

    delete tmp;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    List *l0 = new List;
    List *l1 = new List;
    l0->value = 0;
    l0->next = l1;
    l1->value = 1;
    l1->next = NULL;

    deleteNext(l0);
    deleteNext(l0); // Without the 'if' it will crash here.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `node = tmp` and after that delete tmp you will be deleting the `ListNode`, which `node` points to.

Answer (score 0):

1. As others pointed out, `node = tmp` just changes the argument(local variable)
2. `*node = *tmp` is to copy the content of `ListNode` which is equivalent to
   `node.val = tmp.val; node.next = tmp.next`
3. This function actually removes the next element - it works, but it invalidates the next pointer(if there was something that refers `node->next` as a pointer, it is now a dangling pointer)

Comment: I don't think the next pointer is dangling (because of point 2)

Comment: Well, I mean it works, but should be careful when pointers are already used in other part of code. Probably we wouldn't expect a pointer to get invalidated when its prev node was deleted.

Answer (score -1):

> but why do we need to dereference the pointers?

Let's explore what happens if we don't indirect through the pointers:

```
auto *tmp = node->next;
node = tmp;
delete tmp;
```

This would be equivalent to just

```
delete node->next;
```

---

```
// resulting structure
previous    node             next (deleted)     next next (leaked)
1---------->2----dangling--->_                  4

// desired structure that we get from the correct code
previous    node             next (deleted)     next next
                             _
1-----------3---------------------------------->4
```

So, we end up with wrong node being deleted, and with a dangling pointer in the node that was supposed to be deleted.

---

Note that even the correct inirecting version is broken when attempting to delete the last node.